# How do I connect an Ethernet Jack to LAN8720

Tags: schematics, ethernet, wiring, rj45

I'm looking for a way to correctly connect an RJ45 socket to a LAN8720 chip, but cannot seem to find much information in the datasheets. Here is the datasheet for the LAN8720.
[image]

And here is a data sheet for a generic ethernet connector:
[image]
When I'm creating a PCB, should I connect (in this case) pins 1 and 3 as the TXP and TXN, and then 4 and 6 as the RXP and RXN? Would the case be different if I had for example an ethernet connector with the following schematic?
[image]
In this case would I connect pins 1,2,7 and 8? I'm struggling to understand, any help with this would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: the datasheet shows connections to P1, P2, P3, P6, P7, P8 and P4(P5)

Comment: Hi jstola, thanks for the reply. There are indeed 6 connections on the ethernet datasheet, but only 4 to the LAN8720. I'm not too sure what to make of this...

Comment: The center tap is connected only to the magnetics supply and the termination resistors, but not to the PHY.

Answer (score 3):

Yes to all your questions. You have correctly understood how to map the magjack connctor pins to PHY chip so that they end up correctly through the transformers to the cable.

Now you don't ask about the transformer center taps but again for any magjack the center tap pins, whatever their pin numbers are, need to be connected according to the example diagram.